# Pass Action in method with first argument preset

Tags: c#

I have a Method which handles a message (or command). However mModuleSimulation is an instance of an other class, this class does some asynchronous stuff and when that's done it needs to send the result to a different computer. The class mModuleSimulation has no idea how to send which is why I am sending my SendData method with it so it can simply call that method.

```
public void HandleMessage(ITCCommand command, string address)
{
    mModuleSimulation.ExecuteReceived(SendData, command.Name, address);
}

internal void SendData(string command, string tcAddress)
{
    //DoSend command to address stuff
}
```

Now having to pass down a method is bad enough (at least i don't think it's good practice, might be wrong though). But this method SendData requires an address to send to. I am currently sending the adress down with it as you can see in the example.

later when everything is finished I call it like so:

```
SendData.Invoke(message, address);
```

Is there a way to (without changing the SendData method) only have to do: `SendData.Invoke(message)` so I do not have to pass address through in every method.

Could it be possible to do it somewhat like this (I know this exactly won't work but it's just to give a sense of what I'm asking):

```
public void HandleMessage(ITCCommand command, string address)
{
    Action<string, string> sendDataAction = this.SendData.**SetArgument(arg1 = address)**;
    mModuleSimulation.ExecuteReceived(sendDataAction , command.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing methods (or functions) is perfectly fine - it's back in vogue :)

In your case, a closure is the perfect solution. Your `SendData` method needs two arguments, but you can capture the argument rather than having to pass it manually - lambda functions make this trivial:

```
public void HandleMessage(ITCCommand command, string address)
{
    mModuleSimulation.ExecuteReceived(cmd => SendData(cmd, address), command.Name);
}

internal void SendData(string command, string tcAddress)
{
    //DoSend command to address stuff
}
```

This way, the delegate you're passing already has the `address` captured, and it's own signature is simply `Action<string>`. You hide the implementation details of the `SendData` method from the `ExecuteReceived` method which honestly doesn't care at all - it simply wants to call `Action<string>`.

If this makes you feel uneasy, just think about what a delegate really is - in simple OOP, it's a class that implements an interface with a single method. You can hardly get any *more* OOP than that :D

It's entirely analogous to doing something like this manually:

```
interface ISendData
{
  void SendData(string command);
}

class SendData : ISendData
{
  private readonly string address;

  public SendData(string address)
  {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public void SendData(string command)
  {
    InternalSendData(command, address);
  }
}

public void HandleMessage(ITCCommand command, string address)
{
  var mySendData = new SendData(address);

  mModuleSimulation.ExecuteReceived(mySendData, command.Name);
}
```

You just save up on a bit of unnecessary code :)